# Azure Key management API [Functions keys]

Tags: c#, azure, .net-core, azure-functions

I saw the wiki for the Azure functions.

We have an endpoint to get the Keys of a specific function ([Key management API](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/wiki/Key-management-API)):

GET /admin/functions/{functionname}/keys

Is there an endpoint or an alternative to getting the Keys for all the functions inside a Function App?

Similar to the [Web Apps - List Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/appservice/webapps/listfunctions#code-try-0)

But including the Function keys?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that's not available at the moment, but you can do it in two steps, so 1st step you get the list of functions, and 2nd step you iterate the functions array and request the function key for each of the functions.

Comment: Yes looks like this is what I need to do at the moment